# The two men that tried to kill Dougie in his car, are they from the group with the guys we see in part 6 (the bookies)?

Tags: twin-peaks

I think there are two groups. 1) The bookies and 2) The people that want to kill Evil Cooper(do they think Dougie is Mr. C ?), are those the two men from the previuos episode with the explosive in the car? Or are they working for Evil Coop and that is why they want to kill Dougie/Coop. I know someone gave $500.000 to Ray and Darya to kill Mr.C/evilCoop but i'm confuse.

Please explain what you remember. Oh and now with have the guys from Vegas with Ike "the spike" the midged, so three groups?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are two groups but I'm not certain if or how they are connected. You have group 1) the bookies who Dougie owes money for gambling, and group 2) part of Evil Coop's entourage who are sent to kill Mr C after he comes back as Dougie. I don't believe there are any definitive answers at this time though.